# IDFA - Adsense Webview

Tags: ios

Google has updated its policies for allowing AdSense units to run within web-views on iOS.

I'm incorporating the new "feed" unit into a webview application using AdSense (not AdMob)

Would this require selecting YES to the IDFA?